# Можно ли подключить VK Open API через GTM?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, google-tag-manager

Хочу поставить виджет сообщества на сайт.

В `<head></head>` нужно установить код:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?154"></script>
```

На сайте есть Google Tag Manager. Могу ли я через него поставить этот код?
Как я пробовал:

1. Создал тег "Пользовательский HTML"
2. Туда скопировал вышеприведенный скрипт.
3. Добавил триггер All Pages
4. Выгрузил на сайт.

Не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл такое решение:

```
<script>
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script= document.createElement('script');
script.async = true;
script.src= '/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js';
head.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Теперь записывается между `<head></head>`, но не работает. Как можно исправить ситуацию?